# Replace all underscores in filenames using Ant?

Tags: ant

What would be the best way to do this using an Ant task:

Start with a bunch of text files with names like this:

```
Filename_With_Underscores.txt

Another_Filename_With_Underscores.txt

Yet_Another_Filename_With_Underscores.txt
```

and turn them into this:

```
Filename+With+Underscores.txt

Another+Filename+With+Underscores.txt

Yet+Another+Filename+With+Underscores.txt
```

I actually need to change the identically-named folder that each text file is contained in also, that is, to start with this folder/file structure:

```
Filename_With_Underscores/Filename_With_Underscores.txt
```

and turn it into this:

```
Filename+With+Underscores/Filename+With+Underscores.txt
```

but I can handle that if I know how to rewrite the text file names.

I would know how to replace all underscores with plus signs in the *contents* of a file, using replaceregexp, but how do I do this to the folder and file names themselves?

I've used a mapper to rewrite folder and file names in the past, for example:

```
 <target name="dita_wrap" description="Wraps each file in a folder with the same name as the file, copies all to new location">
    <copy todir="output" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="source"
    includes="*/*.dita" />
     <regexpmapper handledirsep="true" from="^(.*)/([^/]*)\.dita$"
     to="\1/\2/\2.dita" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

However getting something like that to capture and replace each underscore in a filename, no matter how many underscores there might be, is eluding me. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [`<filtermapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#filter-mapper), for example:

```
<copy todir="output" verbose="true">
  <fileset dir="source" includes="*/*.txt" />
  <filtermapper>
    <replacestring from="_" to="+"/>
  </filtermapper>
</copy>
```

Works for me:

```
$> find . -type f
./build.xml
./source/Filename_With_Underscores/Filename_With_Underscores.txt
./output/Filename+With+Underscores/Filename+With+Underscores.txt
```